# Is there any way showing images in alerts in ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to take the values from database such as name,email and photo for a particular user and when he clicks the view button the same details should be seen in popup can i achieve in ionic2..
Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Might be you can try modals https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#modals

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** do it using Alert component.If you need to do that then you have to use page component.On page component where you can show your images and all other db fetched stuff.

*.html*

```
<ion-content padding>
  <img src="{{imageUrl}}" alt="image">
</ion-content>
```

*.ts*

```
 this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
```

Comment: please see the original post above.